# Django ImproperlyConfigured - The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: python, django, celery

I am running a django application using celery. I am getting a strange error in my *tasks.py* file, which is as follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# some code 
# ....
```

Here is the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY must not be empty.
```

In my *settings.py*, SECRET_KEY **is defined**

```
# ...
import myproj.tasks
import djcelery

djcelery.setup_loader()

# ...
SECRET_KEY = '18730s9n9sjxamsuJSismxOIAmso102xjAs'
# ...
```

The application **runs fine if I comment the import** in the *tasks.py* file:

```
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and, more surprisingly, it also runs fine if I make the **exact same imports** in another file (e.g. testfile.py) in the same directory.

Why is this error happening?

**Edit:** Here is my *celery.py* file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')

from django.conf import settings #noqa

app = Celery('myproj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Comment: Did you set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable?

Comment: Yes, it is set in manage.py with `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproj.settings")`

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: I am using Django 1.8.3

Comment: Show us a command you're running to get this error. How do you start Celery?

Comment: Most likely it is a result of circular import somewhere. It's hard to tell where exactly without your entire code base.

Comment: I get the exact same result calling any celery or manage.py command, for example `celery -A myproj worker -B -l info`

Comment: can you post your celery.py? are you using django-celery?

Comment: I updated the question to include celery.py. I am using django-celery 3.1.17

Comment: could it be that you're importing something on your settings file that causes the settings file to be imported in return? (circular import)

Comment: As noted in the docs http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries you can use the path to a task instead of importing the tasks directly in your settings.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I fixed the error, thanks for the help, @Paulo. You should post your answer so I can mark it as correct =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100420/discussion-between-gabriel-ilharco-and-paulo).

Answer (score 5):

The issue was caused by importing the celery tasks into the settings file in order to pass them to the `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` setting.

This import caused a circular import because when the task is imported it will load the settings which only loaded up until the point where the task was imported, thus complaining that no `SECRET_KEY` was configured.

To solve this (and as general best practice), when configuring `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` use the path to the task like so:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.my_task',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}
```

Source http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if Celery doesn't know where to look up your Django settings. Try specifying the celery settings in a separate file:

```
# celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourapp.settings')
app = Celery('yourapp')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

and then marking tasks as:

```
# tasks.py
from yourapp.celery import app

@app.task()
def yourtask():
    pass
```

Comment: I updated my question with my celery.py file, which looks the same as the one you suggested. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Ok, I see. There's a mix of `myproj.settings` and `hub.settings` in your code. Is that an error, or just a not-completely-anonymized code?

Comment: Sorry for that, just a typo. Updated the question